# Getting 'cy.session is not a function' error in Cypress runner

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/08/04/authenticate-faster-in-tests-cy-session-command/) article here to add cy.session() to my login function. However when I do this and then run my test, I get the error `cy.session is not a function`

I've set `"experimentalSessionSupport": true` in my cypress.json config file (and confirmed that my test is seeing this value as true too). From my understanding, that should be all I need to do, but obviously I'm missing something.

I'm using Cypress version 9.4.1. I've tried creating a custom login command instead (exactly as in the article) but just get the same error when running it.

My test works perfectly without the `cy.session()` command.

**login.js**:

```
class LoginPage {    

  ...

  login(username, password) {
     cy.session([username, password], () => {
      cy.visit('/login');
      this.emailField.type(username);
      this.passwordField.type(password);
      this.loginButton.click();
     });
  }

}

export default new LoginPage();
```

**cypress.json**:

```
{
    ...
    "experimentalSessionSupport": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Cypress version 9.4.1.

Welp, this wasn't actually true. I was still on a version that didn't support cy.session(). Silly mistake on my end. It's now all working fine since upgrading Cypress.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Typescript error - `TypeError: cy.[custom command] is not a function`?

If so, the type definition is probably not added yet due to experimental flavour.

Add same definition as you would use for a custom command to the top of the test.

This is taken from the latest release.

```js
declare namespace Cypress {

  interface SessionOptions {
    validate?: () => false | void
  }

  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    session(
      id: string | object, 
      setup?: SessionOptions['validate'], 
      options?: SessionOptions
    ): Chainable<null>
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. No I don't believe it's a TypeScript error as I'm not using any TS files in my project.. everything is JS.